# Is Garden salad still good if it's past the best by date?

Tags: salad, lettuce

I have an unopened bag of garden salad (lettuce, carrots and red cabbage) That is 9 days past the "Best if used by" date. I haven't opened it yet. It still seems crisp when I squeeze it and I don't see any wilting.

Comment: Just open it and try. If it doesn't have mold, smell bad, turn mushy brown or such, it's probably fine. Don't be so paranoid.

Comment: "Don't be paranoid" is probably the worst advice I've ever gotten. I will worry about what's in my fridge and how long it's been there. There is a reason for best by and expiration dates. Not being careful about expired foods can be very dangerous.

Comment: Isn't precut veg considered 2/4 hour, fridge mandatory food?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many salad packages contain freshness preservatives. That is, if the salad remains inside the original packaging, it will maintain its freshness. Regardless of the "best by" date, you should look for crispness of the greens. If the greens are crisp and smell fresh, they are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

A garden salad is best eaten usually up to 5 days past the Best by Date unless you see slime. You will know. The leaves will turn a brown or reddish color.